# Shutdown Idle Threads ExecutorService

Tags: java, multithreading, shutdown, executorservice

Is there a way to tell the `ExecutorService` to shutdown idle threads in a fixed threadpool scenario?

Regards!

::Edit:
Ok, I am getting frustrated. I have now switched to a ThreadPoolExecutor which allows me to specify  keepAliveTime, using the following constructor:

```
private final LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable> threadPool = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>()
public Crawler(String startingUrl, int numThreads, int depth) {

    System.setProperty("http.agent", "");
    // System.setProperty(LocalLog.LOCAL_LOG_LEVEL_PROPERTY, "info");
    this.url = startingUrl;
    this.maxDepth = depth;

    executorService = new ThreadPoolExecutor(
            numThreads, 
            numThreads, 
            2000, 
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, 
            threadPool,
            new ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy());


    databaseHandler = new DatabaseHandler();
    try {
        databaseHandler.init();
    } catch (final SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

// this method is invoked by each Runnable when it found new links
@Override
public void queueLink(String link, int currentDepth) throws Exception {
    if (currentDepth < maxDepth) {
        final LinkFinder lf = new LinkFinder(link, currentDepth, this);
        executorService.execute(lf);

    } else {
        System.out.println("max depth reached!");
        System.out.println("num queued tasks: " + threadPool.size());
    }
}
```

Each new Runnable receives a current depth property. On the last line of each Runnable currentDepth is raised by 1. Of course "max depth reached" is printed out as expected, as well as "num queued tasks: 0". The threads however continue running for hours.

I was operating under the impression that the params keepAliveTime and TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS would ensure that after two seconds of idle-ness, the thread was shut down (given there are no other tasks queued).

What am I missing? I mean, I can just count the of times I hit the else statement and then shut the executor down manually, but since ThreadPoolExecutor already offers a time-based behavior, I'd rather stick to that.

Right now I assume it has something to do with the policy I have set... Gonna look into that. Thanks anyways

Regards!

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html

show me the methode ;)

Comment: You need to go to the javadoc for your implementation.

Comment: A fixed size pool by definition is fixed.  What you really want if perhaps a cached pool with a maximum size?  Why do you want to shutdown these threads?

Comment: I have been following a tutorial by Madalin Ilie elaborating about the use of ExecuterService vs. ForkJoinPool by means of a simple web crawler: 
http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-10-2011/111004-jtip-recursion-in-java-7.html?page=1
I try to expand her example with a maxium depth to crawl. So when all threads have reached the maximum depth, they just remain doing nothing. I have now started to look at the ThreadPoolExecutor implementation of ExecutorService, which has the afore mentioned setKeepAliveTime method implemented. I just wonder what BlockingQueue I should use.

Answer (score 0):

`setKeepAliveTime(long time, TimeUnit unit)`

**or**

You may reduce the thread pool size dynamically by  `setCorePoolSize(int corePoolSize)`